# Can't get Youtube Node ( xpath is right )

Tags: xpath, youtube, nodes

I copied the xpath from Opera ' s dev tools.
That is the code in my clipboard :

```
//*[@id="yt-masthead-container"]
```

and i pasted intto my codes.But node returned null all the time.
I will delete this node but i can t reach it.
Please help.
Thanks all (:

Note : i m opening youtube and trying remove a div.div's  id is ;

```
yt-masthead-container
```

That is my code;

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=aerosmith");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        htmlTemizle(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
    }

    private void htmlTemizle(string html)
    {
        try
        {
            string xPath = "/div[id='yt-masthead']";
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            var n =  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xPath);

            textBox1.Text = n.InnerHtml;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            textBox1.Text = e.Message;
        }
```

Comment: i m working on youtube page's html.

Comment: By `"/div[id='yt-masthead']"` did you mean `"//div[@id='yt-masthead']"`?

Comment: but both of them return null.